# rsfso mathcal not printing properly

Tags: math-mode, mathcal

When I use `\mathcal{P}` in the `rsfso` package, the output looks fine on the screen, but when I print, the right-hand side of the "P" does not print. Any advice?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rsfso}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{P}$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: No problems here with the MWE. Exactly how do you print? Are the fonts embedded into the file? I compiled using pdflatex from TL17 and printed via Evince on Linux

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using TexShop on a mac. I also tried compiling using pdflatex on the command line, and got the same problem. I don't know how to control whether the fonts are embedded into the file. Do you know how to control that?

Comment: If you are using a proper modern LaTeX installation it should be automatic. Try printing from something else than TeXShop, for example Adobe Reader (when it is a PDF file)

Comment: I've just discovered that xelatex from the command line works. Thanks for the help, daleif.

Comment: Pdflatex should also work. Exactly which latex installation are you using? It is usually listed at the top of the `.log` file